# In Dart, how to type a method so that it returns an instance of the type passed as an argument?

Tags: dart, generics, types

I am learning Dart, and as a task, I want to create a dependency injection container. However, I have reached a point where I have stored and used the type as an argument of a method, but I don't know how to tell Dart that the method's return type should be the type passed as an argument. The issue is that I'm not passing the instance, but rather the type as a Type variable.

What I wanted is to somehow associate the generic with the Type argument. This is an example, in this case, the program gives an error because the instance returned is not of type Bar, but the IDE should already warn me about this because I'm passing the type Foo as an argument to the Get method.

I could achieve this in PHP using class-string as a comment.

```dart
void main() {
  T get<T>(Type type) {
    ClassMirror classMirror = reflectClass(type);
    return classMirror.newInstance(Symbol.empty, []).reflectee;
  }

  Bar foo = get(Foo);

  print(foo);
}

class Foo {}

class Bar {}
```

Comment: Dispatch to statics (such as constructors) cannot happen with generics.  This is a fundamental design choice of Dart.  You can dispatch at runtime to a limited set of static methods, and you'll find examples of that in json-to-objects mapping tools, for example.

Comment: So, would I have to use a generic type like Object and wouldn't have the typing of the object that came from my container?

Comment: There almost nothing that you can do with a `Type` instance.  It's not necessary anyway; use `get<Foo>()` instead of `get(Foo)`.  However, doing that won't be particularly useful either if your goal is to instantiate the object (for the reasons that @RandalSchwartz mentioned).  Instead you can have `T get<T>(T Function() newInstance)` and then call `get(Foo.new)`.  Also, if you want reflection, you should use a code-generation-based approach (see [`package:reflectable`](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable)).